# Replacing div if there is any validation error connected with the div value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an input group:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.StorageId)
    </div>
    @if(ViewData.ModelState["StorageError"] !=null && ViewData.ModelState["StorageError"].Errors.Count>0)
    {
        <div class="a" title="@ViewData.ModelState["StorageError"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="storage">
            @Html.DropDownList("storageId", null, new { @class = "form-control",@style="border-color:red" })
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="a" title="@String.Empty" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="storage">
            @Html.DropDownList("storageId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

As you can see, if there are no errors, the site should render `div` without a red border and tooltip.

Do you think it's efficient and good-looking enough to leave it as it is, or does it need to be rewritten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, 95% of your code is the same between the two sections, so I'd prefer to use just a single instance with a `bool` on the page.

```
@{ 
    var error = ViewModel.ModelState["StorateError"];
    var hasErrors = error != null && error.Errors.Any();
}

<div class="a" title="@( hasErrors ? error.Errors[0].ErrorMessage : string.Empty" )
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="storage">
        @Html.DropDownList("storageId", null, new { @class="form-control",
            @style=" @( hasErrors ? "border-color:red", string.Empty ) })
</div>
```

You should also get into the habit of using `.Any()` instead of `Count() > 0` as `Any` will stop iterating after it finds the first item that matches the filtering (usually not a big deal, but the collection could get rather large, and it's a minor change to coding that could give big performance enhancements).

The only other thing I might recommend would be to have a CSS class for `border-color:red` instead of inline styling.

Comment: After changing all `@{...}` in to `@(...)` all works and looks like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, thanks. Sorry for that. It was first thing this morning, and it's been a month or two since I wrote in Razor. I'll edit.